# Internet Explorer cross-domain AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

I have created an Internet Explorer extension. It injects a script every time I enter any page, which sends an AJAX request to my localhost.
The problem is, it should use HTTP, so if the request is sent from the HTTPS page, I'm getting an "Access Denied" error. Is there a way to fix it?
I'm running IE11, set the "Access data sources across domains" option to "Enabled".
Thanks!

Comment: I'm fairly confident that the AJAX protocol needs to be https if you are viewing an https page.

Comment: Ya, I don't think this would be a Across Domains problem, it'd be a browser security flag to make an AJAX request that's not HTTPS on an HTTPS page.

Comment: @PeterMark so there is no browser setting to allow these kind of requests? :(

Comment: @DmitriyKozyatinskiy See below.

Answer (score 0):

You [can](http://wiki.sln.suny.edu/display/SLNKB/Enabling+mixed+content+in+Internet+Explorer) change the setting to allow mixed content here:

Tools -> Internet Options -> Security -> Custom Level -> Miscellaneous -> Display Mixed Content (enable it).

This is, of course, not a good solution for anything but a private site, and will leave your browser insecure everywhere (not just on your page).

Comment: For some reason, it didn't help. After changing this setting, I'v restarted the browser, but still "Access Denied".
Tested with next request:

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8111/', true);
xhr.send();

Comment: You could try a different browser - https://support.pearson.com/getsupport/s/. Also, check your address. Is that semicolon supposed to be there? And if you're trying to pull from you locahost within a https website... it sounds like an unstable setup.